# Approach for writing a single function that deals with different messages

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns

I have a function which saves a message in a database. There are different scenarios for saving messages based on types. For example I have Save Message, Save Message for Repair, and Save Message from XML.

Would a sensible approach be to create a single function with a parameter which specifies the operation type, and to have a switch case to choose between calling three different methods?

I have come up with this so far:

```
public bool SaveMessage(Message message,
                        List<Image> images,
                        List<Attachments> attachments,
                        string type);
```

and have three other methods: `SaveMessage()`, `SaveMessageForRepair()`, and `SaveMessageXml()`.

Is this a reasonable approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use **Strategy Pattern**.

> Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them
>   interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from
>   clients that use it.

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a object which encapsulates all the information including Message Type and pass this to function which save this message in database. Now the target function will decide where to save and how to save.

In this way, it will be easy to override the behavior and extend the functionality if a new message type is introduced in the system.